# convert years into days using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have data frame which look like this

```
 A    B
    FIN $500
    CERA    4 days 
    CARCERA 180 days 
    PRABA   1 years 
    feat    4 years 4 YEARS 
    Pods    3 years 
    FIN     $250
```

i want to change years into days for example 1 year have to change 365 days, 4 years have to change 1460 days

Expected output:

```
 A       B
    FIN    $500
        CERA    4 days 
        CARCERA 180 days 
        PRABA   365 days 
        feat    1461 days  1461 days 
        Pods    1095 years 
        FIN     $250
```

Comment: Why is feat duplicated? Is column B of type str or datetime?

Comment: wouldn't 4 years have 1461 days (leap year)?

Comment: it is str @Celius Stingher

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elegant solution but here you go:

```
def func(a):
    b = str(a).split(' ')
    if len(b)>1:
        if b[1]=='years':
            return str(int(b[0])*365)+" days"
        else:
            return a
    else:
        return a


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = ['FIN','CERA','CARCERA','PRADA', 'feat']
df['B'] = ['$500', '4 days', '180 days', '1 years', '4 years']
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
    A   B   C
0   FIN $500    $500
1   CERA    4 days  4 days
2   CARCERA 180 days    180 days
3   PRADA   1 years 365 days
4   feat    4 years 1460 days
```

As @Nullman correctly pointed out, you'll have to edit the function to include leap days.